# Python telnetlib to connect to Scrapy Telnet to read stats

Tags: python, scrapy, telnet, telnetlib

I have a Scrapy spider running for days. I usually try to check stats as how many items it has scraped and so. I simply run following cmds in terminal and it gives me stats.

```
$ telnet [IP] [PORT]
>>> spider.name
alf-spider
>>> stats.get_stats()
...
```

Now I want to do this with Python using telnetlib but I can't achieve above results. Following is my python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.1.5"

def main():
    ports = ['6023']
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        ports = sys.argv[1].split(',')

    for port in ports:
        get_stats(port)

def get_stats(port):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port)
    tn.write("spider.name\n")
    print tn.read_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Above code if ran just hangs until force closed. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code? Adding printouts so you can understand where this code hangs?

Comment: Yes. tn.read_all() never returns.

Comment: ok, so maybe this gives us a clue? `Telnet.read_all()
Read all data until EOF; block until connection closed.`

Comment: Yes it seems server is not sending any response. That's why it's stalled.

Comment: well, try to send `"spider.name\r\n"`

Comment: Already tried that. Nothing changed

Comment: Is there a way I can write after few seconds of connection is made?

Comment: Do you have `wireshark` installed? can you sniff and see what's the difference between the python way and the cmd way?

Comment: You can read first, wait for the ">>> " string

Comment: I have already tried read_until(">>>")

Comment: read_until(">>>") works by the fact it returns.

Comment: I just figured write("quit()\n") makes read_all() return but with empty response.

Comment: I found the solution! read_until worked out if changed slightly.

Comment: Way to go :) "glad I could help"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.1.5"

def main():
    ports = ['6023']
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        ports = sys.argv[1].split(',')

    for port in ports:
        get_stats(port)

def get_stats(port):
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port)
    tn.read_until('>>>')
    tn.write("spider.name\n")
    print tn.read_until('>>>')
    tn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```